# Does anybody know how to create code snippets in Mozilla Bespin

Tags: code-snippets, bespin

Anybody know how to create code snippets in Mozilla Bespin. Its strange that there's so little documentation about it. How do snippets works? are they directly loaded from a js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skywriter doesn't really support snippets yet. We had a trivial sample plugin. A future release will support more powerful snippets like TextMate's.